# Declaration of list of type python

Tags: python, list

Let's suppose to have a class `Bag` that contains a `list` of `item`.
What we know about `item` is just that it has a method called : `printDescription()`.

Now I want to define a method `printAllItemsDescription` inside `Bag`, that invokes the method `printDescription()` on each `item` inside items `list`.

This should be the code (it's wrong but I think should looks like this) :

```
class Bag:
    items:list[item] = []
    .
    . 
    .
    def printAllItemsDescription(this):
        for item in this.items:
            item.printDescription()
```

My problem is that I don't know how to tell python that my `items` is a `list of item`.
I know I can do something like `item:Item` but don't know how to do it with lists.

Then while iterating on `items` it will know that each item contains a method called `printDescription()`, but on this moment `item` is just a variable of undefined type.

P.S. : I tried also to do something like `x:list[item]` but I got this error :

```
Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes
```

Comment: @luk2302 compiler wrote : Subscript for class "list" will generate runtime exception; enclose type annotation in quotes. It doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: You need to refer to instance variables with `this`, i.e. `for item in this.items`. Also, by convention, Python programmers call this variable `self`, not `this`. It's not *incorrect* to do the latter, but it will confuse people.

Comment: If the compiler is worried about type annotations causing problems, use `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your file. I recommend doing this anyway; it's a significant improvement over the old way Python did annotations.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yeah I did it but forgot, I will update code but the problem remains because "items" is still a class of undefined type because compiler doesn't allow me to define it.

Comment: Filling in the missing classes and whatnot, your code works fine for me. [See for yourself](https://tio.run/##dY/NCsIwEITvfYrFU3MpqLeCB0UPPkOREDXRhTQJyQr69DU/tBbFPWWY3W8m7kV3a9bDoLztgXP1oIeXnAP2znoCYYwlQWhNqKqLFiEAkuzbCuJcpQLn0dBehotHl9bqILVixU@T/XpxeIreaQktW7ARtBO3speIodUYqEvPUzXROUeDxPk3Nckmn8EGutlBjttqfUzevBbdMcwAyvocC2ggWQX28cdazc//Yv2zuC1jbuwfVRSrSWSrsBrhnDTXOomaseL8rceG4Q0 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it worked! Thanks a lot if you move it as "answer" I'll sign it as response.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python's type hinting is ever-evolving, and they've made some changes over time. Older versions of Python don't support subscripting `list` as in `list[item]`. Fortunately, we can get around all of this using [a future import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). The `annotations` import from `__future__` works in all Python versions starting from 3.7 and effectively pretends that all type signatures are wrapped in quotes so they don't cause issues at runtime.

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Bag:
    items: list[Item]

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def printAllItemsDescription(self):
        for item in self.items:
            item.printDescription()
```

Also, I've made a few minor changes to fit with Python's style. Instance methods should generally have their first argument called `self` for consistency, and classes (like `item`) should be written starting with a capital letter, so if you have control over the class `item`, I would recommend changing it to class `Item`.